# Wrap OAuth middleware in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

We have custom `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` implementation and use direct calls like `/token` to authorize users.

I have a thoughts to wrap some native auth calls (like `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`, `GrantCustomExtension`, `GrantRefreshToken` etc.) using ApiController - that's how I'll be able allow or reject any forbidden calls and do other serving stuff.

Is that correct practice or not? What is the way?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you switch to IdentityServer3.

Comment: @Kahbazi why? We just migrated from this peace of legacy

Comment: If you're stuck on owin, you should move to IdentityServer3, but if you could migrate to .net core, definitely move to IdentityServer4.

Comment: @Kahbazi we're going to migrate to .net 5 later, but right now I need investigate the question above